# Prove that a non-decreasing function has zero derivative

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-decreasing function (i.e., $x \leq y \implies f(x) \leq f(y)$). Suppose at a point $a \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a sequence of positive numbers $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n \to 0$ and
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(a + x_n) - f(a - x_n)}{x_n} = 0.
$$
I would like to prove (or find a counterexample) that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f'(a) = 0$. In particular, I'm trying to show that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(a + x) - f(a - x)}{x} = 0.
$$
If I pick an arbitrary $x > 0$ so that $x_n \leq x < x_m$ for some $n, m \geq 1$, I can get the bound
$$
\frac{f(a + x) - f(a - x)}{x} \leq \frac{f(a + x_m) - f(a - x_m)}{x_n}
\leq \frac{f(a + x_m) - f(a - x_m)}{x_m} \cdot \frac{x_m}{x_n}.
$$
The problem is that $x_m / x_n$ may be large if, for instance, $\{x_n\}$ converges to $0$ too rapidly. Does anyone know how I might be able to proceed?

Comment: If even you show that your ratio tends to $0$ it does not follow that $f$ is differentiable at $a$. I suspect that there is a counter-example.

Comment: If the ratio tends to $0$, then wouldn't you be able to find some interval $(0, \delta_1)$ such that for all $x_n, x_m \in (0, \delta_1)$, $x_m / x_n < 1$? Then if I'm not mistaken, because $[f(a + x_m) - f(a - x_m)] / x_m$ tends to $0$, there would be a smaller interval $(0, \delta)$ such that $[f(a + x) - f(a - x)] / x < \varepsilon$ for all $x \in (0, \delta)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample: Let $x_1 = 1/2$ and $x_{n+1} = x_n^2$. Then $(x_n)$ is strictly decreasing and tends to $0$, also $2x_{n+1} = 2x_n x_n < x_n$ when $n\ge 2$. Define

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if } x\le 0, \\ x_n^2 & \text{ if } x\in (x_{n+1}, x_n].\end{cases}$$

Then

$$\frac{f(0+x_n ) - f(0-x_n)}{x_n} = \frac{x_n^2}{x_n} = x_n\to 0$$

as $n\to \infty$, but one can find $2x_{n+1} \in (x_{n+1}, x_n)$ so that

$$ \frac{f(y_n) - f(0)}{y_n} = \frac{x_n^2}{2x_n^2} = \frac 12 .$$

Thus $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.